# Is it possible to display bars based on two values in Recharts Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, bar-chart, recharts

I have to represent the below array in a chart using Recharts Js library. I want the Y axis to represent the **cost** property and the X axis to represent the **volume** property and the chart must be a bar chart (requested by the client).
Basically, the bar must grow in height based on their cost but they also have to grow in height based on their volume and that's what I'm struggling with: I can't find a way to display the bars based on their volume too. In this picture it's possible to see the [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRTZr.png), it was sent me by the client but be aware that the visual representation might not be exact and consistent with the data.

**What I've tried:**
I tried to draw the bars "manually" using the *shape* prop in the *Bar* component and setting a width based on the **volume** value but it's just a weak workaround because the scale of the X axis won't be consistent with the bars. I also tried to set the width with the *barSize* prop but this only affects the height in case of a horizontal chart

Example of data array:

```
[
    {
      volume 1500,
      cost: -136.06243,
      totalVolumeCost: -204093.645
    },
    {
      volume 1000,
      cost: -272.12486,
      totalVolumeCost: -294166.97366
    }
]
```

**Question:** How can I set the bars width in order to display the volume value?

**What I got so far:** https://codesandbox.io/s/overall-cost-implication-forked-1sumje

Answer (score 0):

I tried to accomplish it with a BarChart, but it doesn't seem possible: You can edit the BarGap, but there is no override for the container of each bar.

An alternative that still uses Recharts is this codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/area-chart-with-variable-rectangle-widths-h8o780?file=/src/App.tsx

The data format needs some modification, but i've written a loop for that:

```js
//Init edited data data
let dataAdjusted = [{ volume: 0, cost: 0 }];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let currentData = data[i];
  dataAdjusted.push({
    volume: dataAdjusted.at(-1).volume,
    cost: currentData.cost
  });
  dataAdjusted.push({
    volume: dataAdjusted.at(-1).volume + currentData.volume,
    cost: currentData.cost
  });
}
```

It works by supplying the `fill` parameter of the `Area` element with a gradient:

```js
<Area dataKey="cost" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="url(#gradient)" />
```

The gradient takes the modified data and adds gradient stops for each color.

```js
        <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0">
          {dataAdjusted.map(function (d, index) {
            let cost = d.cost;
            let volume = d.volume;
            let percentage = 100 * (volume / totalVolume);
            let fill = "#111111";
            if (cost > 0) fill = "#d9f7be";
            if (cost > 5) fill = "#b7eb8f";
            if (cost < 0) fill = "#ffd8bf";
            if (cost <= -5) fill = "#ff9c6e";
            return <stop offset={`${percentage}%`} stopColor={fill} />;
          })}
        </linearGradient>
```

It still needs some labeling work, and probably some corrections in the gradient function, but it should be a start for your problem.

Comment: That's quite interesting, I would never thought  to use the AreaChart. Quick question: as you can see in the picture, I also need to add multiple labels, is it possible with this type of chart?

Comment: I've adjusted the codesandbox to include some labels. It still needs some position work, but it should give you an idea how to get the desired labels.